# Wildcard for content in an XNA content project?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, xna

I have an XNA 3.1 content project (.contentproj) with the following:

```
<ItemGroup>
<Compile Include="tiles\B000N800.BMP">
  <Name>B000N800</Name>
  <Importer>TextureImporter</Importer>
  <Processor>TextureProcessor</Processor>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="tiles\B000N801.BMP">
  <Name>B000N801</Name>
  <Importer>TextureImporter</Importer>
  <Processor>TextureProcessor</Processor>
</Compile>
(... and so on ...)
</ItemGroup>
```

What I'd like to do is be able to specify a wildcard so that `tiles\*.bmp` gets compiled instead - so that I don't have to keep re-synchronising the content project when I add and remove textures from the "tiles" directory.

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Ideally the solution would ignore the hidden ".svn" directory, under "tiles". And also the content project would continue to work in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a blog post by Shawn Hargreaves that describes how to do this for XNA 1.0:

[Wildcard content using MSBuild](https://web.archive.org/web/20160310041551/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/shawnhar/archive/2007/06/06/wildcard-content-using-msbuild.aspx)

Based on that, here is what I did which works with XNA 3.1 (and doesn't cause those weird _0 to appear):

Create a separate "tiles.proj" file with the following content:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="3.5">
<ItemGroup>
  <WildcardContent Include="tiles\**\*.BMP" Exclude="tiles\.svn\*">
    <Importer>TextureImporter</Importer>
    <Processor>TextureProcessor</Processor>
  </WildcardContent>
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <CreateItem Include="@(WildcardContent)" AdditionalMetadata="Name=%(FileName)">
    <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="Compile" />
  </CreateItem>
</Target>
</Project>
```

And in the original ".contentproj" file, right before `</Project>`, add:

```
<Import Project="tiles.proj" />
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to use wildcard in your item definition :

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Include="tiles\**\*.BMP"
           Exclude="tiles\.svn\*">
    <Name>%(Compile.Filename)</Name>
    <Importer>TextureImporter</Importer>
    <Processor>TextureProcessor</Processor>
  </Compile>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks - that worked nicely. Also I've found that `<Visible>false</Visible>` can be added to prevent it from being accidentally clobbered in Visual Studio.

Comment: Actually - it's only working for me because I'm not checking the names at the moment. It seems the output is actually being named "B000N800_0.xnb", "B000N801_0.xnb" and so on... (an additional "_0" is being appended).

Comment: I've tested it locally and I don't have an additional "_0" on my xnb files in Content directory. That's strange